# & after bash command

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I'm not sure what the `&` after the command in this bash script is doing.

```
    python alt_pg ${args} &
```

Also the original version of the script that I'm modifying does not use 'python' at the start of the command is that something to do with the '&'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're two separate things.

Running `python alt_pg ...` means `python` will be looked up in `$PATH`, and `alt_pg ...` will be passed as arguments to python. Python then looks for a file named `alt_pg`. Running `alt_pg ...` means `alt_pg` will be looked up in `$PATH`. The latter may cause python to run anyway, depending on what `alt_pg` does.

Adding a `&` after the command means the command runs in the background, and the shell can continue with commands that follow even when `alt_pg` is still running.

Answer (score 7):

`&` at the end of the line runs `python alt_pg ${args}` in the "background" under your linux shell; however, the script is still associated with the shell.  Therefore, if the shell stops, so does the script.

Side note: You can disassociate the script from your shell by using `nohup python alt_pg ${args} &`.  If you spawn the script like this, the script persists after logging out of the shell.

Answer (score 3):

The ampersand runs the process in a forked/background process.